# How do I make my WCF service accept soap message with Content-type of "text/xml"?

Tags: .net, wcf, soap, ssl

How do I make a WCF service accept soap message with Content-type of "text/xml" instead of "application/soap+xml". I have to host the service on SSL. Hence I'm using wsHttpBinding with security mode "Transport". Because I use wsHttpBinding, I think, content-type of request is forced to "application/soap+xml". Am I missing something here? What wrong am I doing?

Comment: Just out of interest why you are wanting to change the content type?

Comment: Its a requirement - to support legacy application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, wsHttpBinding does assume SOAP messaging.  But, if you define a custom binding, then you have the ability to change the SOAP version to "None".  It's a property in the text encoder binding element.

Here is an example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738456.aspx

If you're going to be doing a lot of this, then you should probably be looking at ASP.NET Web API.  It provides support for XML and JSON formatting automatically.  You can do it using WCF, but if you're goal is to build REST web services, then you'll find ASP.NET Web API is better suited for this.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization